# Optimization algorithm for list of consecutive resources

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

Given a list from 1 - 12, assuming I use each number every 10 minutes, **how do I maximize the number of minutes between close numbers.**

In other words, maximize the difference between each value in each spot of the list.

Trying to maximize the time between n & n+1, but also n & n+2, and n & n+3

1 next to 2 is the worst.  1 next to 12 would be best, however it would end up causing closer numbers further down the list.

For example,

1 2 3 ... Would not be optimal because 1 and 2 are only 10 minutes apart.

1 12 2 11 ... Would not be optimal because 1 and 2 are only 20 minutes apart.

1 5 9 2 6 ... Would be more preferable because the number are further apart.

**Is there an optimal Delta between each that could be calculated given the number of items in a list?**

Comment: Is the question _"how do I maximize the number of minutes between each **consecutive** number?"_

Comment: ...and are you trying to maximize the sum of the number of minutes between every pair of consecutive numbers (even though some consecutive numbers may be very close), or are you trying to maximize the smallest such gap in the sequence (in other words, trying to make the number of minutes between each consecutive pair as even as possible)?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough and I don't know how to phrase it well, maybe you can help me out.  This should apply to not only consecutive ranges, but also attempt to find the sequence with the most difference between all numbers, so 1, 3, 5 might not be optimal either because 1 and 3 are still closer together, where 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10... would be better.

Comment: trying to maximize the time between n & n+1, but also n & n+2, and n & n+3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the input values in the set are evenly spaced, I would recommend using the following approach to define the sequence.

Step through the ordered values, jumping X number of values each time, where X is defined as the total number of values / Phi.
Pretend that the end of the set of values circles back to the beginning.

So for the set of values 1 - 12, you'd have:

X = 12 / Phi

X = 12 / 1.618 = 7.4

Round off 7.4 to the nearest integer, so let's assume X = 7.

Then your sequence would be 1, 8, 3, 10, 5, 12, 7, 2, 9, 4, 11, 6

To quantify (or score) how "maximized" this sequence is, you would take the sum of the following calculation for EVERY member in the set.

For EACH set member, calculate the absolute value of the difference in "value" between itself and each other member divided by that "distance" to that member.
For example, for the member 8 in the above sequence, its score would be:

8,1 = |8-1| / 1 = 8

+

8,3 = |8-3| / 1 = 5

+

8,10 = |8-10| / 2 = 1

+

8,5 = |8-5| / 3 = 1

+

8,12 = |8-12| / 4 = 1

+

...

Do that for each member of the set and take the sum to get the overall "score".
The higher the score, the more "maximized" the sequence will be.

Comment: +1 This seems to yield great results. You might want to elaborate on why using the golden ratio (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) is such a great strategy for defining the sequential increment.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for any positive n, the best answer is having the odd numbers in ascending order concatenated with the even numbers in ascending order.

With 1-12 we have 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12. There is an hour's worth of distance between consecutive numbers.

**Implementation (Ruby)**

```
def optimize_resources(n)
  answer = Array.new(n)
  for i in 1..n
    if i % 2 == 1
      answer[(i - 1) / 2] = i
    else
      answer[(n - 1) / 2 + i / 2] = i
    end
  end
  answer
end
```

Comment: This "feels" correct to me too, although I'm not sure why. +1 if you can prove it.

Comment: Certainly we cannot do better than an hour for everything. Even if we loosen the problem to optimizing distances between pairs 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, etc. Say 1-2 is 7 spaces apart. Then there are 6 empty slots in the middle, but we have only 5 pairs remaining, so actually two numbers from the same pair will enter the slot. Hence we will get a distance of at most five.

Comment: Up vote, however, not exactly the answer I was looking for.  I want the greatest distance between each number, so 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, 4, 8, 12 would be more preferable